# How can I make a density scatterplot with log scale in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'd like to make a density scatterplot with log10 scale in R. I tried to plot it using *ggplot* and *stat_density2d* in R. I used this code:

```
ggplot(data=vod_agb_df, aes(vod, agb)) + 
       stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE, n = 100) + 
       scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'YlOrRd', direction = 1) +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.25), limits = c(0, 1)) + 
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 300, 50), limits = c(0, 300)) + 
       labs(x='L-VOD', y='AGB(Mg/ha)') +
       theme_bw()
```

But the result looks strange. [the density scatterplot with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HYo7.png)

[This is the plot I want to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEQmC.png)
[The original scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwMR0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `log10`-transform the density; here's a minimal & reproducible example

```r
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2020)
mvrnorm(100, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), 2, 2)) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    ggplot(aes(V1, V2)) + 
    stat_density2d(
        aes(fill = log10(..density..)), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE, n = 100) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'YlOrRd', direction = 1) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

### Update

It's not clear to me what you mean by *""I'd like to make the density scatterplot in the point distributed area, not the whole area of the plot.""* If you're asking how to increase the height of the gradient colour bar, you can do the following

```r
set.seed(2020)
mvrnorm(100, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), 2, 2)) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    ggplot(aes(V1, V2)) + 
    stat_density2d(
        aes(fill = log10(..density..)), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE, n = 100) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'YlOrRd', direction = 1) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barheight = unit(3.5, "in"), title.position = "right"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. But it seems that the colored density plot is the **Minimum Bounding Rectangle** of the scatter points. I have posted the original scatterplot in the question.

Comment: @changkx I don't know what you mean by "minimum bounding rectangle". The gradient colour scale maps to the log10-transformed density. I thought that's what you were after (the plot you show suggests as much)? Or do you want to log10-transform values on the x and/or y axes?

Comment: Yes, the log10-transformed density is what I want. But according to the original scatterplot (I updated it in the answer). I'd like to make the density scatterplot in the point distributed area, not the whole area of the plot.

Comment: @changkx *"I'd like to make the density scatterplot in the point distributed area, not the whole area of the plot."* I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you mean. What's the "point distributed area"? Are you perhaps asking how to increase the height of the gradient colour scale to match the height of the plot?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and informative response. Sorry for my confusion. As shown in the _"The original scatterplot"_, there is an approximate linear relationship. So, I'd like to plot it as density scatterplot just like the _"sample plot"_ in the question.

Comment: I’ve just used some random sample data to have something to work with as you don’t provide any data. Just adjust my example to match *your* data and Bob‘s your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever plot you are showing as your expected output for that you can use following code

```
library(tidyverse)

# Bin size control + color palette
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length) ) +
  geom_bin2d(bins = 20) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'YlOrRd', direction = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this answers OPs question: (1) OP wants to show a 2d *density* plot, you're showing *counts*. (2) OP would like to *log10-transform* the density; you don't log-transform the data.

Comment: Yes, Maurits Evers. You are right. If the counts could be replaced by log10-transfromed density, that's what I want, just like the sample plot.